# TranslateAnimation with RelativeLayout and SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, translate-animation

Straight to question, I currently have `SurfaceView` inside a `RelativeLayout` as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/surfaceframe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a requirement to make the `RelativeLayout` along with its `SurfaceView` to move. Easy.

```
mPlayerFrame.setTranslation(distance);
```

This `mPlayerFrame` is variable for the `RelativeLayout.`

However, I also have to support API level 10. The client insists on doing so. I came up with this chunk of code after browsing here and elsewhere.

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,distance,distance);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setDuration(0);
mPlayerFrame.startAnimation(anim);
```

With the above code, I could see that `mPlayerFrame` is moving but the playback (`mPlayerView`, the `SurfaceView`) apparently did not move at all.

So far I have tried the followings:

- Setting an animation to `mPlayerView`

  ```
  mPlayerView.startAnimation(anim);
  ```
- Setting offsetTopAndBottom

  ```
  mPlayerView.offsetTopAndBottom(distance);
  ```

  it does move using this, but at a much faster rate than the rate of which `mPlayerFrame` is moving.

So to summarize, I have a `SurfaceView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and I want to move this `RelativeLayout` along with its `SurfaceView` child around. Easily achievable using API level 11+ but I had to support API Level 10 as well.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have difficult with old Animation Framework, you could use great Library that add compatibility of API11 ObjectAnimator to old Android Platform:

> [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

There is some differences between this Library and the new one, especially the fact that the new actually move the object to the new position and the library just show image of it, so I recommend that you split your code according to API level.

Comment: hey, great! It works. It was a legacy project, so I didn't expect that it includes nineoldandroids. Pleasantly surprised to see it there :)